# Invoke unique functions of derived classes from a vector of pointers to base class objects

Tags: c++, class, derived-class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    void speak() { cout << "Hello!"; }
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    void func1() { cout << "I'm a function!"; }
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
    void func2() { cout << "I'm also a function!"; }
};

int main()
{
    vector<Base*> v = { new Derived1(), new Derived2(), new Derived1(), new Derived2() //, ...
    };
    // For each Derived1 object invoke func1() and for each Derived2 object invoke func2()
}
```

Base is not polymorphic (no virtual function). From these conditions how can I be able to invoke func1 for each Derived1 object and func2 for each Derived2 object in v?

Comment: If nothing at all can be changed about this setup, then I don't believe there's any good way. But if you could change the vector to hold something else, then one idea would be having it store a polymorphic wrapper around the non-polymorphic class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As-is, it's impossible. You can't do `dynamic_cast`, no member that indicates one type or the other. There's absolutely no way to distinguish given a `Base*` whether it's a `Derived1*` or a `Derived2*`.

You would have to do one of:

1. Add a `virtual void func() = 0;` that the two different classes would override.
2. Add a member  variable of type `std::function<void()>` that would be set in the `Base` constructor differently by the two `Derived` classes.
3. Add a member variable that's an enum to indicate which `Derived` it is, so that you could do a switch externally to do a safe `static_cast`.
4. Add a `virtual ~Base()` so that that instead of a switch, you would do `dynamic_cast`s.
5. Not actually have either `Derived1` or `Derived2` inherit from `Base`, but instead have a `variant<Derived1, Derived2>`.
6. ???
7. Profit.

Answer (score 1):

> *"Base is not polymorphic (no `virtual` function)."*

You still can do a `static_cast<Derived1>(v[0])` / `static_cast<Derived2>(v[1])`, a.s.o, as long you're sure what you'll get at a particular index.